# Configuring Load Balancer with Cross-Project Backends for App Engine, Buckets, and Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-load-balancer

I've managed to set up a cross-project backend for an External Regional Application Load Balancer, which works fine with Cloud Run. However, I'm looking to achieve the same configuration, especially with Cloud Functions and Buckets back-end service

The Global Load balancer setup accepts functions and buckets but it only allows backends within the same project, but I want to have cross-project backends for App Engine, Buckets, and Cloud Functions.

Has anyone successfully configured this type of Load Balancer setup? Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK, it's not yet possible.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you already mentioned that your concern was working in [External Regional Application Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-reg-ext-shared-vpc#cross-project). Based on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/set-up-global-ext-https-shared-vpc?cloudshell=false#cross-project) Global External Application Load Balancer can now  accommodate cross project backend.

Same with the description of Regional Load Balancer, Global Load Balancer can reference backend services (and backends) located across multiple service projects, this is based from the documentation.